# Applet war project doesn't find applet class in jar

Tags: java, applet

I have the following projects

```
>projectJar
>projectWar
```

Inside projectJar I have a class that extends Applet, the class's name is com.me.test.TestApplet. Then in the war project I include the jar and create an HTML file like the following...

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>A Simple Program</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<APPLET code="com.me.test.TestApplet.class"
    archive="WEB-INF/lib/projectJar.jar" WIDTH=256 HEIGHT=240> </APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

However, when I try to load the applet I get a class not found exception for TestApplet. Can anyone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot serve a "PATH" under "WEB-INF". Move your "projectJar.jar" to another folder, perhaps "/jar/porjectJar.jar".

Comment: Ok this is great advice, is there an easy way to do this in eclipse? It seems to want to default to the WEB-INF directory in the Assembly info.

Comment: That's a completely different question! I'm not sure how you have your eclipse project(s) setup. You could always use a Servlet (or something else) to serve the file out of "WEB-INF".